# How to use groupby to create a new column with two associated columns？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Assuming I am a fruit seller who has bought 3 kind of fruits separately, Now I want to calculate my average cost and how many times I bought it.

The input dataframe is:

```
data = {
    'fruit':['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'apple', 'banana'], 
    'unit_price':[10, 11.5, 5, 20, 12, 4.5], 
    'amount':[100, 200, 50, 300, 180, 90]
}
pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    amount   fruit  unit_price
0     100   apple   10.0
1     200   apple   11.5
2      50  banana    5.0
3     300  cherry   20.0
4     180   apple   12.0
5      90  banana    4.5
```

For example, I have bought apple 3 times and the average cost is (100*10 + 200*11.5 + 180*12)/(100+200+180)=11.375

Here is what I want:

```
     fruit  avg_cost  count
0    apple     11.375      3
1    banana    4.679       2
2    cherry    20.0        1
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [23]: def my_agg(df):
    ...:     names = {'Count':df['unit_price'].count(),'avg_cost':((df['amount']*df['unit_price'])/df['amount'].mean()).mean()}
    ...:     return pd.Series(names,names.keys())

In [27]: df.groupby('fruit').apply(my_agg).reset_index()
Out[27]: 
    fruit   avg_cost  Count
0   apple  11.375000    3.0
1  banana   4.678571    2.0
2  cherry  20.000000    1.0
```

Comment: That's not what I want, the mean in your answer is simply the mean value of unit_price, not average price. Do you have better idea? Thanks.

Comment: It works! And it really helps me understand groupby and aggregate function. Thanks for your time!